# How to prove $\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma^H \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H$ has a inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I want to prove this matrix has inverse matrix

$\mathbf H_{AB}$ is a $2$ by $7$ matrix,now i do SVD to $\mathbf H_{AB}$,that is $\mathbf H_{AB}=\mathbf U \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H$

Now,i want to prove that 
$\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma^H \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H$ has a inverse matrix ,i mean,if now $\mathbf B=\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma^H \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H$,then $\mathbf B^{-1}$ exists, and $\mathbf B\mathbf B^{-1}=\mathbf B^{-1}\mathbf B=\mathbf I$

Comment: What are the sizes of $U,\Sigma, V$ in your SVD?

Comment: If i do SVD,the size of $U,\Sigma,V$ will be $2 by 2$,$2 by 7$ and $7 by 7$

Answer (score 1):

The inverse pf $\mathbf{B}$ exists only if the diagonal square matrix $\mathbf \Sigma^H \mathbf \Sigma$ has non zero diagonal entries. So your $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ which looks like this
$$\mathbf{\Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &\sigma_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$$
(or it's transpose) should maintain $\sigma_{1,2} \neq 0$

Comment: So in your thinking,$\mathbf B$ shouldn't have inverse matrix?

Comment: that's not what I said. If $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ are both non-zero, then your inverse exists.

Comment: because when i use matlab to test it,B is singular matrix,and the singular value is not zero,that is ,$\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are both not zero,can you tell me the reason that when the $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are both nonzero,then its inverse exist?

Comment: you should instead be testing for $\mathbf U \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf \Sigma^H \mathbf U^H$ since $ \mathbf \Sigma^H \mathbf \Sigma$ is $7 \times 7 $ and will always have at least 5 zero diagonal entries.

Comment: If you insist on testing for $\mathbf V \mathbf \Sigma^H \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf V^H$, you should consider a reduced version by omitting rows/columns 3 till 7 that correspond to zero eigenvalues.